# Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.RelationshipType] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method

Tags: java, javascript, json, angularjs

I have the below angularJS code to parse the JSON in .js file:

```
$scope.updateAssociations = function() {
             $scope.productModel = angular.toJson($rootScope.relationShipModel);
             alert($scope.productModel);
             var requestObj = { "channelCode": $rootScope.userSelectedChannel,
                    "modelTypeName" : $rootScope.selectedHierarchy.hier_name,
                    "relationShips" : $scope.productModel,
                    "associations" : $scope.selection,
                    "relID" : $routeParams.relID,
                    "prdCmptId" :  $routeParams.prdCmpntId,
                    "associationsModelTypeName" : $rootScope.associationsModelTypeName
                 };
            var result = $http.post('updateAssociations.do', requestObj);
            result.success( function(response)
            {

            }
});
```

I am not getting the "relationShips" value in the Java class:

```
ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(requestBody);
RelationshipType relations = mapper.readValue(node.get("relationShips"), RelationshipType.class);
```

While the code try to retrieve value from mapper, I get the below exception:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.cpc.as.bean.RelationshipType] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method.
```

My relationShips JSON is:

```
[
{
"chnl_code":"BMG Catalog",
"rel_id":"59",
"rel_type_name":"product collateral assignment",
"entity_type_name":"generic feature",
"entity_role":"parent",
"related_to_entity":"collateral",
"related_to_crdnlty":"m",
"related_to_role":"child",
"dsply_name":"Collateral",
"hier_flag":null,
"related_to_object_type":"product",
"sub_role":null,
"atrbt_ind":"n",
"dpndnt_flag":"n",
"rel_ind":"n",
"dsply_model_type_name":null,
"sub_dsply_name":null,
"gen_new_flag":"y",
"allowDefaultSearchFlag":false,
"custom_price_type":null,
"rls_type":null,
"gradeMatrixRelated":false,
"releaseDriven":false
},
{
"chnl_code":"BMG Catalog",
"rel_id":"55",
"rel_type_name":"feature family assignment",
"entity_type_name":"generic feature",
"entity_role":"parent",
"related_to_entity":"feature family",
"related_to_crdnlty":"m",
"related_to_role":"child",
"dsply_name":"Feature Family",
"hier_flag":null,
"related_to_object_type":"group",
"sub_role":null,
"atrbt_ind":"n",
"dpndnt_flag":null,
"rel_ind":"n",
"dsply_model_type_name":null,
"sub_dsply_name":null,
"gen_new_flag":"y",
"allowDefaultSearchFlag":false,
"custom_price_type":null,
"rls_type":null,
"gradeMatrixRelated":false,
"releaseDriven":false
}
]
```

Can someone please help what's going wrong in my code. Thanks in advance.